# ReactJs not able to call the express API when click in Electron

Tags: express, electron

I am trying to invoke an express API when I click a button in React running in Electron environment but it does not work.

What is working is I did a console log in the login function and when I click the button it did print out the value in the console.

I also did the console log at the user/login api, though it did not print out the values, but it did print out that the MongoDB is connected successfully. I'm wondering what have I missed. Here are the codes:

Main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow,Menu, shell} = require('electron')
const server = require('../../server.js')
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev')

process.env.NODE_ENV = "development"

const isMac = process.platform === "darwin" ? true : false

let mainWindow
let aboutWindow

function createMainWindow (){
     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width:1024,
        height:768,
        show: false,
        backgroundColor:"#263238"
       
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`)

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.focus();
      });

      mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(event, url){    
        event.preventDefault();  
        shell.openExternal(url);
    })
}


app.on('ready', () => {
    createMainWindow()
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu)
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu)

    mainWindow.on('ready', () => mainWindow = null)
})

const menu = [
    ...(isMac ? [{
        label: 'app.name',
        submenu:[
            {
                label:'About',
                click: createAboutWindow
            }
        ]}]:[]),
    {
        role:'fileMenu'
    },
    ...(!isMac ? [
        {
            label:'Help',
            submenu:[
                {
                    label:'About',
                    click: createAboutWindow
                }
            ]
        }
    ]:[]),
    ...(isDev ? [
        {
            label:'Developer',
            submenu:[
                {role:'reload'},
                {role:'forcereload'},
                {role:'separator'},
                {role:'toggledevtools'},
            ]
        }
    ]:[])
]

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (isMac) app.quit()
  })

  app.whenReady().then(() => {
        app.on('activate', function () {
      if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createMainWindow()
    })
  })
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const connectDB = require("./dbconfig/dbconfig");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const userRoute = require('./routes/user')

dotenv.config()
connectDB()
const cluster = require('cluster')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:5000'];
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: whitelist}));

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(morgan('dev'))

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use('/api', userRoute)

app.use(express.static(path.join("frontend", "build")))

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "build", "index.html"))
})

require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello from server started by Electron app!");
    console.log(`Listening to part ${port}...`)
 }).listen(port)
```

User Route

```
router.post('/user/login',  async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

React env file

```
REACT_APP_FETCH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

React Login Component

```
const login = async (e) => {
    console.log(loginData)
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await Axios.post(
    process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + "/api/user/login",loginData,{ withCredentials: true });
    if (response.data.statusCode == 200) {
      setLoading(false);
      window.location.replace("/test");
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };


<button type="submit" onClick={login} className="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg font-weight-semibold auth-form-btn" disable={loading}>
 {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" ></i>}
 &nbsp;Sign In</button>
```

Package JSON Proxy

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^13.1.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.7",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-serve": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "electron-build": ""
  },
  "build":{

  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "main": "public/main.js",
  "homepage": "./"
}
```

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. I now know that it was the jwt causing the issue after I did a try and catch and console log the error.

My apology and sorry for the inconvenience caused.